# I change the capitalization of a directory and Git doesn't seem to pick up on it

Tags: git, macos

I'm developing a project on OS X Lion that is under Git version control. I had these lowercase directories and then later capitalized them (e.g. emailaddresses => EmailAddresses), but Git doesn't seem to recognize the change. It still thinks the directories are lowercase when I run `git ls-files` and other commands.

Is this harmless, or should I do something else to get Git to pick up on this change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: Changing capitalization of filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/git-changing-capitalization-of-filenames)

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You're probably using case insensitive (but case preserving) HFS+. I usually work round this like so:

```
$ git mv somename tmpname
$ git mv tmpname SomeName
```

Comment: Had the same problem with the Github for Windows tool. Again the above solution works around the issue nicely: rename to a temporary file in Windows Exploer, then - after committing - rename to the final name with the correct case.

Comment: Or do it in one command: git mv --force somename SomeName (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16071375/217866)

Comment: For the changes to be reflected in the remote repo you also need to `git push origin master`. If git refuses to update the remote you may need to add a dummy file (e.g. `touch stam`) and do the push. Followed by a subsequent delete of stam and push again.

Comment: @SagunKho: try `git mv --force somename SomeName` instead.

Comment: One thing to note is that you need to be in the folder where the file is for this to work. It was not obvious for me at first and I kept getting >>>  bad source, source=somename, destination=tmpname <<< because I was trying to run the command from the root of the repo.

Comment: Does not work even with `--force` because Git says the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 611):

You can tell git to take account of the case by running

`git config core.ignorecase false`

Comment: Really great answer if you have already changed the file names without using git mv --force or some other CL script. Thank you!

Comment: This is the superior answer as I didn't particularly feel like git mv'ing 200 renamed files manually!

Comment: for some reason it duplicated all the files, now I have both the original versions and the ones with capitalization changed...

Comment: @Salatiel I guess it duplicates them when you're already tracking the file.

Comment: I needed to remove the previous files in my local repo if I change the names (literally just tu capitalize the files) in the remote one (like GitHub).

Comment: bear in mind using this command will give duplicated files/folders when pushing files/folders with same name but different capitalization in case insensitive OS (Windows)

Comment: I found this left me with no noticed working directory changes (despite names not matching what's on git). Deleting, staging, undeleting the files, and staging again made them get noticed after I did this.

Comment: This answer causes problems on case-insensitive filesystems and is explicitly not recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369235/8869677

Comment: this one did the trick for me, second time I faced the same problem and found the same answer - this worked for MacOs

Answer (score 45):

### How to git mv on Mac Case-Sensitively

This is happening because Mac OS X implements case preserving and case insensitivity features that are intended to help you.

Although the double rename suggestions in the other answer will work, I recommend the use of '--force' for a best practice result:

```
$ git mv --force somename SomeName
```

Note: if you try without the force option, git will barf on you like this:

```
$ git mv somename SomeName
$ fatal: destination exists, source=somename, destination=SomeName
```

In the above example, the git command fails and no files are changed in the filesystem or in git's index.

Comment: Upon the first command, I get `fatal: not under version control`.

Comment: That fatal error means you do not have a GIT repository at that location. `git` commands only work in directories with GIT repositories.

Comment: But I was in a subdirectory of my Git repo… In the end, I solved it via [Taran's  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it/31393409#31393409), BTW. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Try to change git config option core.ignorecase to false in your .gitconfig file.

Comment: or write `git config core.ignorecase false`

Comment: @iforgotmypassword = you should have answered it - I would have voted for you actually

Answer (score 22):

The following steps helped me resolve the issue:

1. Rename the folder to `temp`:

   ```
   mv Folder temp                  // It will rename your Folder to temp
   ```
2. Stage and commit:

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "Temp"
   ```
3. Rename `temp` folder to your choice:

   ```
   mv temp folder        // It will rename temp folder to the name of your choice(folder)
   git add .
   git commit -m "Folder Fixed"
   ```

Done - You can now push.

Comment: It worked great. Thank a lot

Comment: You can also accomplish this without the first commit; simply rename, stage, rename, stage, then commit.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this is that LINUX-based OS or macOS ignore case sensitive for file/folder name. We need to resolve this problem by the below steps

```
For Exp, you want to change folder name from Base to base
1. mv Base base2
2. git add . && git commit -m "Fix folder name problem (wip)"
3. mv base2 base
4. git add . && git commit -m "Fixed folder name problem"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do `git mv AAA aaa` or `git mv -f AAA aaa`, it will not be work and you will have error `fatal: renaming 'AAA' failed: Invalid argument`.

Because `AAA` and `aaa` are **ONE SAME** folder/file on case-insensitive file systems, move `AAA` to `aaa` means move `AAA` as `aaa/AAA`.

So you should do

```
git mv AAA aaa.1
git mv aaa.1 aaa
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

None of these actually helped me, I still was having git tell me to stash my changes, because my situation was that my local folder was capitalised but the remote not, and my branch was behind and I could no longer pull because of file capitalization differences in the folder structure.

The only way I could fix this was deleting my local branch and checking out the remote.

Answer (score -2):

You can also do this manually without using GIT commands. Inside the `.git` folder, simply delete the folder with the name you want i.e `SomeName` . And then rename the folder `somename` to `SomeName`. More details at : [How to fix folder name set to uppercase and git convert to lowercase](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/How-to-fix-folder-name-set-to-uppercase-and-git-convert-to/qaq-p/629515)