# On OSX, git merge deletes file with renamed capitalization

Tags: macos, git, merge, git-merge

I wrote this script and ran it on OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion, on the default case-insensitive HFS filesystem.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
# create git repo
rm -rf caps
git init caps
cd caps
# commit empty file called "file"
touch file
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
# create branch called "branch"
git branch branch
# rename "file" to "File"
# using --force per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582
git mv --force file File
git commit -am "renamed capital"
# switch to branch, make a non-conflicting commit
git checkout branch
touch newfile
git add .
git commit -am "branch commit"
# merge master into branch, commit merge
git merge --commit --no-edit master
# but where's the renamed File?
more File
```

When the script was done, it failed on the last line, when it should have succeeded:

```
+ git merge --commit --no-edit master
Removing file
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 file => File | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename file => File (100%)
+ more File
File: No such file or directory
```

git status showed this:

```
$ git status
# On branch branch
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    File
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

We can get the file back at that point with `git checkout File`, but it's very easy at that point to accidentally commit the deletion.

We've been renaming quite a few files lately, fixing their capitalization, and this has bit our team a lot. Is there a git setting or best practice we can use to workaround this problem? (For now, we're just telling everybody to be extra extra careful.)

Comment: Interesting.  What is your `core.ignorecase` setting?

Comment: I'm on OSX, so git-init and git-clone automatically set core.ignorecase to true. If I set it to false, I'm unable to merge from master at all, with this error: "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: File".

Comment: I can't reproduce this with git 1.7.5.4 on Mac OS or Git for Windows 1.8.4.  `file` is accurately renamed to `File` for me, following the steps you provided.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't repro on git 1.7.5.4 for OS X, but it does repro on 1.8.4. That let me run a bisect which turned up https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7cb99ada26be5d86402a6e060f3ee16a672f16 which indicates that the problem only occurs when renaming empty files. (I bet you didn't use an empty file on Windows?)

Comment: Interesting.  I did not use empty files; I wouldn't have expected that you had a lot of empty files that needed case-changing renames.  Interesting find!

Comment: Ah, but it looks like it still fails badly whenever rename detection fails. My script just happened to fail rename detection due to empty files, but if you replace "file" with a completely different "File", the new File will be deleted after merging!

Comment: That's a hell of a bug.

Comment: @DanFabulich note: git 2.0.1+ should solve that issue: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978787/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue ("deletes file with renamed capitalization") is *precisely* what [commit ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683) by [David Turner (`dturner-tw`)](https://github.com/dturner-tw) solves:

#### [`merge-recursive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ae352c7f37ef2098e03ee86bc7fd75b210b17683/merge-recursive.c): fix case-changing merge bug

> On a case-insensitive filesystem, when merging, a file would be wrongly deleted from the working tree if an incoming commit had renamed it changing only its case.
>   When merging a rename, the file with the old name would be deleted -- but since the filesystem considers the old name to be the same as the new name, the new file would in fact be deleted.
>
> We avoid this by not deleting files that have a case-clone in the index at stage 0.

That means that, starting git 2.0.1+ (June 25th, 2014), the merge should now work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem only occurs when rename detection fails.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/235889

It just so happens that git disabled rename detection of empty files in git 1.8. https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7cb99ada26be5d86402a6e060f3ee16a672f16

This script runs as expected on git 1.7 and git 1.8:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
# create git repo
git --version
rm -rf caps
git init caps
cd caps
git config --get core.ignorecase
# commit empty file called "file"
echo file > file
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
# create branch called "branch"
git branch branch
# rename "file" to "File"
# using --force per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582
git mv --force file File
git commit -am "renamed to File"
# switch to branch, make a non-conflicting commit
git checkout branch
echo newfile > newfile
git add .
git commit -am "branch commit"
# merge master into branch, commit merge
GIT_EDITOR=true git merge --verbose --commit master
ls File
git status
```

But this script fails, due to a bug in git:

```
#!/bin/sh -x
# create git repo
git --version
rm -rf caps
git init caps
cd caps
git config --get core.ignorecase
# commit empty file called "file"
echo file > file
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
# create branch called "branch"
git branch branch
# rename "file" to "File"
# using --force per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582
git mv --force file File
echo "completely different content" > File
git commit -am "renamed to File"
# switch to branch, make a non-conflicting commit
git checkout branch
echo newfile > newfile
git add .
git commit -am "branch commit"
# merge master into branch, commit merge
GIT_EDITOR=true git merge --verbose --commit master
ls File
git status
```