# Changed case of filename but GIT won't forget the old version

Tags: macos, git

Due to upgrading an app to be PSR-0 complient (uppercase class file names) I have changed classes to have uppercase filename. ie. `users.php` has become `Users.php`. That's worked fine and git has noticed the changes and pushed to the remote repo.

My problem is that if I now change the contents of `Users.php` at all. Both the old `users.php` and new `Users.php` appear as changed files to be staged.

How do I get git to forget about the lowercase version of the file?

Note. I'm using osx which ignores casing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I change the capitalization of a directory and Git doesn't seem to pick up on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it) (and see also: [Git: Changing capitalization of filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849))

Comment: Git has picked up the change. It's just that now both files seem to exist (although only in git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Git repository if have two files Users.php, users.php

- if you donot want users.php file you can remove that file from your git repository by using the following command `git rm filename`
- To untrack a single file that has already been added/initialized to your repository, i.e., stop tracking the file but not delete it from your system use: `git rm --cached filename`