# Git: file name reverted to legacy name after each clone

Tags: java, git

I used to have file named `ViewMVC.java` that contained declaration of `ViewMVC` class.

Later, I decided to rename the class to `ViewMvc`. As a result, file's name changed to `ViewMvc.java`. I pushed this change into remote a long time ago.

The problem I face is that when I clone remote repo, the file is pulled as `ViewMVC.java` (the class name is `ViewMvc` as expected). In other words - for some reason the name of the file gets reverted to a legacy name.

I tried to change the name again and push into remote, but the issue is not resolved this way.

Any ideas why this happens and how could I resolve this annoying issue?

Comment: What OS are you using?  I'm wondering if Windows case-insensitive filesystems are playing a role in the chaos...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I'm using a mix. My desktop is Windows, laptop is OSX, and now I'm trying to bring up continuous integration server on centOS. But I tend to believe that the original commit that changed the name of the file was made on Windows...

Comment: Both Windows and OSX use case-insensitive matching by default, so that `MVC` and `Mvc` are the *same file*. Git has a configuration knob, `core.ignoreCase`, to tell it whether to believe those are the *same file* or *different files*. Simply tweaking the knob is not quite sufficient as Git's use of the knob is to sense how the OS will handle it, and you need *both* Git *and* the OS to be case-sensitive (as CentOS is) here. As for the best way to fix it, well, I avoid Windows; I could test on OSX but have not, so do not know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523849/changing-capitalization-of-filenames-in-git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26014660/changed-case-of-filename-but-git-wont-forget-the-old-version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in the comments, I think the problem is that git didn't actually think you'd changed anything when you renamed the file.  You want it to see `ViewMVC.java` as deleted and `ViewMvc.java` as a new file (which it will sometimes report as `ViewMVC.java renamed to ViewMvc.java`), but I'm guessing because of the case-insensitivity settings it just said "nah, nothing changed that matters."

The problem, then, is that the tree object - essentially a text file that reads like a directory listing - has the old capitalization still.  Again because of the case insensitivity settings, it will happily address the file using a different capitalization if one exists that way in the work tree; but on clone it defaults to the capitalization in the tree object.

*So,* you have to get it to update the tree object (ideally in each tip commit that you care about).

On a system with case-sensitive fs (and git config set accordingly) you could simply clone the repo, move the file (again), `git add .` , use `git status` to confirm that it sees a rename, and commit.

To fix it on a Windows system, the only thing I can think to try would be to delete the file, commit, then recreate the file with correctly-capitalized filename and commit again.

Comment: By "recreate", of course, I mean something like `git checkout HEAD^ -- ViewMVC.java`, rename the file, then `git add` etc etc

Comment: Great explanation. I ended up just changing the name on centOS machine and pushing the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This happens on our project from time to time whenever somebody renames a file which is the same name with a different case.

It's because git is case-insensitive by default, you can change it in settings, but the easiest and quickest solution would be to rename the file to ViewMvc1.java > commit and push > rename again to ViewMvc.java > commit and push.