# git core.ignorecase = false in Mac OS X

Tags: git

I have made `core.ignorecase=false` at local and global level of configuration , yet I see strange behaviour as shown below when I do `git checkout MASTER` (not master).I also did `git branch -v` but no MASTER was shown.

```
git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

git branch
* master

git checkout MASTER
Switched to branch 'MASTER'

git branch
master
```

We can see there is no (*) now on `master`.
**I know Mac OS X file system is case insensitive** , but then

a) What is left for significance of   `core.ignorecase=false` of explicitly mentioning it if even after this Our OS controls it ?

b) Why is there no (*) at master branch if git is assuming MASTER and master as same ? [ EDIT : Even if you make core.ignorecase = true , we will still see this ]

Doing rev-parse , both point to same SHA1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By setting `core.ignorecase=false` you have **misconfigured** your system and you should set this to the correct value, `true`, if you expect Git to behave reasonably. From [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) manual:

> Internal variable which enables various workarounds to enable Git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like APFS, HFS+, FAT, NTFS, etc. For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when Git expects "Makefile", Git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember it as "Makefile".
>
> …
>
> Git relies on the proper configuration of this variable for your operating and file system. Modifying this value may result in unexpected behavior.

The correct value is `true` on macOS, unless you have specifically formatted your disk or partition as case sensitive. So you should never change this value unless the value selected by Git is incorrect. For example, the value will be incorrect if you copy a repository from a case-insensitive volume to a case-sensitive one, since Git does not probe the value after repository creation with `git clone` or `git init`.

I’m not sure what you expected to achieve by setting this variable to `false`, but the only thing that actually happens is that Git does not work correctly.

---

Note that from my tests, Git will not get the branch names correct on case insensitive filesystems if you specify branches with the wrong case. You can call this a bug in Git if you wish, but speaking from experience, getting nice behavior on case-insensitive filesystems can be difficult.

Comment: As far as I understand the answer , this `core.ignorecase` is used by git to be compliant with OS and not to override its default working with cases - wether sensitive or insensitive ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: It is not possible to override how the OS handles file cases.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: If you want case-sensitive files on macOS, create a partition, disk image, or APFS volume using a case-sensitive filesystem. In the *Disk Image* application, you can create a new blank image using “Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)” or you can create a new APFS volume using “APFS (Case-sensitive)”.

Comment: `Git does not probe the value after repository creation with ..` , So, you are saying if I push a repo from mac os x to git hub and some one cloned that on windows os , git won't change the value of  `core.ignorecase` ? Do git push , pushes my local configurations too ?

Comment: Repository configuration is not cloned, pushed, or pulled.

Comment: ok but then what did you meant by `Git does not probe the value after repository creation with ..` . I am not able to get this part. please elaborate it a little bit more. rest I have understood.

Comment: Git checks the correct value of `ignorecase` only once, and that is when you create the repository. Remember that when you `clone` a repository, what you are really doing is creating a new repository.

Comment: Why did git even expose to us this facility ? It seems git is intelligent enough to set the correct value ? Is there any case where git can also go wrong - thats why gave us this config value to override in those cases ?

Comment: Git exposes everything—there is nothing that Git hides from you. Take a look at the `git config` manual, you will see a staggering number of different variables, including (for example) `core.repositoryFormatVersion` which you should **absolutely not modify.** Git only sets the correct value of `ignorecase` when you create the repository. If you move the repository to a different filesystem, it may no longer be the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Your OS / file system is case insensitive and will return a file which has alternative case within it's name. It's a one way trap door for the unwary.

Note the lack of the `*` against any of the listed branches when changing to the incorrectly cased branch `MASTER` - your OS returned the details from branch `master` (same filename), and checked that out. Now Git can't find `MASTER` in its list of available branches.

A similar issue exists on Git-for-Windows and this comes up regularly. It's not easy to resolve (code v humans).