# Build of React application on AWS Amplify fails in Amplify Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify

I can locally publish my application to the S3 bucket and the application works. But deployment through AWS Amplify console (web) fails on the Build step of the backend.

The build step of the backend fails because of a missing configuration file or directory.

```
{
  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/codebuild/output/src145745747/src/aws-service-catalog/amplify/backend/auth/cognito8f0f2f1d'
      at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
      at getCfnFiles (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/lib/push-resources.js:337:20)
      at updateS3Templates (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/lib/push-resources.js:350:39)
      at packageResources.then.then.then.then (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation/lib/push-resources.js:42:17)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'scandir',
    path: '/codebuild/output/src145745747/src/aws-service-catalog/amplify/backend/auth/cognito8f0f2f1d'
}
```

Anybody has tips how to debug/resolve this problem?

Comment: `cognito8f0f2f1d` correspond to the folder containing the auth config that you added using `amplify auth add`. So, you might be missed to add that folder into version control.

Comment: @CastroRoy yes I think that is the problem. My .gitignore was too tight and did not include that directory. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

See my reply on the thread above. The directory was not included in my git repo.

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that aws amplify is not showing any details on build failure even on debug mode.

The solution is **recloning the app** and test locally and then push the changes.

The problem happens to be Git is missing changes. This git issue is resolved by following this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899582/i-change-the-capitalization-of-a-directory-and-git-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-on-it)

[image]